# Angular 6 Routing Shows Blank Page no errors

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to follow an Angular tutorial [Angular Material Tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-beautiful-apps-with-angular-material/)

Initially, I was getting a blank page after adding routes. I fixed this by adding the routes directly to the app.module.ts file, instead of in a separate routes module. (I followed a different routing tutorial for this work-around, but I'm not sure why this helped).

Now, I added authentication, and I'm back to a blank page.

There are no errors, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Here is the project in its current state with the problem [blank_page_problem on GitHub](https://github.com/BenyominWalters/angular-material-blog/tree/blank_page_problem)

Any idea? (Let me know if you need any specific file views.)

Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded the repo and it works, have you tried to restart the CLI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.component.ts you are handling Authentication inside constructor() {}.
Do that in ngOnInit() {}

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
}
```

After this it worked for me.
Also

> import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

in auth.service.ts throws an error 
*TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'auth0-js'.*
Add

> "@types/auth0-js": "^8.11.2",

to your dependencies in package.json. Check this - [auth0-js could not find a declaration file or module](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/496)

Path: ' '

[image]
Path: 'dashboard'

[image]

You aren't having the auth check for dashboard route

```
<a mat-list-item
  routerLink="/dashboard">
  <mat-icon class="icon">dashboard</mat-icon>  
  <span class="label">Dashboard</span>
</a>
```